# Tensorflow model accuracy not increasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am currently doing the Deep Learning course on Udacity and am presently trying to complete the 4th assignment, where you are supposed to create your own model and see what the best accuracy you can achieve on the noMINST dataset.

I have tried to implement the VGG 16 model but have been running into a few problems, initially, the loss was going straight to nan, and so I changed the last activation function from relu to sigmoid, but now the accuracy does not improve and is stuck on around 0-6% so I'm guessing my implementation is wrong but I can't seem to see the mistake, I would greatly appreciate any help or advice!

Bellow is my full code other than reading in the dataset as this code was provided by so I'm guessing it's right.

```
pickle_file = 'notMNIST.pickle'

with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as f:
    save = pickle.load(f)
    train_dataset = save['train_dataset']
    train_labels = save['train_labels']
    valid_dataset = save['valid_dataset']
    valid_labels = save['valid_labels']
    test_dataset = save['test_dataset']
    test_labels = save['test_labels']
    del save  # hint to help gc free up memory
    print('Training set', train_dataset.shape, train_labels.shape)
    print('Validation set', valid_dataset.shape, valid_labels.shape)
    print('Test set', test_dataset.shape, test_labels.shape)

image_size = 28
num_labels = 10
num_channels = 1  # grayscale

import numpy as np


def reformat(dataset, labels):
    dataset = dataset.reshape(
        (-1, image_size, image_size, num_channels)).astype(np.float32)
    labels = (np.arange(num_labels) == labels[:, None]).astype(np.float32)
    return dataset, labels


train_dataset, train_labels = reformat(train_dataset, train_labels)
valid_dataset, valid_labels = reformat(valid_dataset, valid_labels)
test_dataset, test_labels = reformat(test_dataset, test_labels)
print('Training set', train_dataset.shape, train_labels.shape)
print('Validation set', valid_dataset.shape, valid_labels.shape)
print('Test set', test_dataset.shape, test_labels.shape)


def accuracy(predictions, labels):
    return (100.0 * np.sum(np.argmax(predictions, 1) == np.argmax(labels, 1))
            / predictions.shape[0])


batch_size = 16
patch_size = 5
depth = 16
num_hidden = 64

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():
    # Input data.
    tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(
        tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size, image_size, num_channels))
    tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
    tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
    tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

    # Variables.
    l1_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 1, 64], stddev=0.1))
    l1_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64]))
    l2_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 64, 64], stddev=0.1))
    l2_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64]))

    l3_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 64, 128], stddev=0.1))
    l3_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([128]))
    l4_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 128, 128], stddev=0.1))
    l4_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([128]))

    l5_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 128, 256], stddev=0.1))
    l5_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([256]))
    l6_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 256, 256], stddev=0.1))
    l6_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([256]))
    l7_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 256, 256], stddev=0.1))
    l7_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([256]))

    l8_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 256, 512], stddev=0.1))
    l8_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512]))
    l9_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 512, 512], stddev=0.1))
    l9_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512]))
    l10_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 512, 512], stddev=0.1))
    l10_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512]))

    l11_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 512, 512], stddev=0.1))
    l11_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512]))
    l12_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 512, 512], stddev=0.1))
    l12_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512]))
    l13_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 512, 512], stddev=0.1))
    l13_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512]))

    l14_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([512, num_hidden], stddev=0.1))
    l14_b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_hidden]))

    l15_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden, num_labels], stddev=0.1))
    l15_b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_labels]))


    # Model.
    def model(data):
        conv_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(data, l1_w, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + l1_b)
        conv_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(conv_1, l2_w, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + l2_b)
        max_pool_1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv_1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

        conv_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(max_pool_1, l3_w, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + l3_b)
        conv_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(conv_2, l4_w, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + l4_b)
        max_pool_2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv_2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

        conv_3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(max_pool_2, l5_w, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + l5_b)
        conv_3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(conv_3, l6_w, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + l6_b)
        conv_3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(conv_3, l7_w, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + l7_b)
        max_pool_3 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv_3, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

        conv_4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(max_pool_3, l8_w, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + l8_b)
        conv_4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(conv_4, l9_w, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + l9_b)
        conv_4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(conv_4, l10_w, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + l10_b)
        max_pool_4 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv_4, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

        conv_5 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(max_pool_4, l11_w, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + l11_b)
        conv_5 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.nn.conv2d(conv_5, l12_w, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + l12_b)
        conv_5 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.nn.conv2d(conv_5, l13_w, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + l13_b)
        max_pool_5 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv_5, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

        shape = max_pool_5.get_shape().as_list()
        reshape = tf.reshape(max_pool_5, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])
        hidden = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(reshape, l14_w) + l14_b)
        return tf.matmul(hidden, l15_w) + l15_b


    logits = model(tf_train_dataset)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf_train_labels, logits=logits))

    # Optimizer.
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

    # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
    train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_valid_dataset))
    test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_test_dataset))

num_steps = 1001

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print('Initialized')
    for step in range(num_steps):
        offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
        batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :, :, :]
        batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset: batch_data, tf_train_labels: batch_labels}
        _, l, predictions = session.run(
            [optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        if step % 50 == 0:
            print('Minibatch loss at step %d: %f' % (step, l))
            print('Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(predictions, batch_labels))
            print('Validation accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(
                valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels))
print('Test accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [@cyniikal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10219147/cyniikal), your network seems too complex for this dataset. With a single layer model, I was able to achieve 93.75% accuracy on the training data and 86.7% accuracy on the test data.

In my model, I used `GradientDescentOptimizer` that minimized `cross_entropy` just as you did. I also used a size `16` batch-size.

The main difference I see between your approach and mine is that I:

1. OneHot Encoded the labels
2. Used a single-layer network rather than VGG-16

See this [notebook with my single layer model code sample](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QQGwt0_ImeB-xnugOHw2aJhWqmdz9Pxq).

If you would like to add layers to your neural network (the network will converge with more difficulties), I highly recommend reading [this article on neural nets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-tensorflow-mnist/#0). Specifically, since you added `sigmoid` as your last activation function, I believe you are suffering from a [vanishing gradient problem](https://medium.com/@anishsingh20/the-vanishing-gradient-problem-48ae7f501257). See [this page](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-tensorflow-mnist/#7) to address the `vanishing gradient`.

Comment: Good eye! Actually, One-Hot encoding the labels could definitely be the answer here. Using softmax for the output of the network means that the output will be squished into (0,1], so softmax could be coming up with some wonky probability distributions given the label vector.

Comment: I actually think labels are one-hot encoded using this line ? `labels = (np.arange(num_labels) == labels[:, None]).astype(np.float32)`

Comment: hm, I searched in your code and I don't see that line you mentioned @HenryHargreaves. That line would OneHot Encode the labels as mentioned by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526035/understanding-applied-to-a-numpy-array). To be more explicit, I think it would be better to use sklearn's OneHotEncoder.

Comment: @StephanieMarker apologies, I've updated the original post that shows the full source code; also I greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with the learning_rate might yield better results, but it could be that your network is just too complex (computing a super non-convex function) for simple Gradient Descent to work well here. Other than that I don't spot any immediate issues, but debugging a neural network implementation can be pretty tricky sometimes.

Try out a quick switch to AdamOptimizer or another advanced optimizer or toying around with the learning_rate. If you're still getting super low test accuracy, then I'll try to go through it with a fine-toothed comb later.

Comment: Hi cyniikal, thanks for getting back to me, I've changed the optimiser to the AdamOptimizer and I've also played around with the LR as well but to no avail. I'm not sure this will help but this is the output when training.
`Validation accuracy: 10.0%
Minibatch loss at step 250: 2.335239
Minibatch accuracy: 0.0%
Validation accuracy: 10.2%
Minibatch loss at step 500: 2.346944
Minibatch accuracy: 0.0%
Validation accuracy: 10.2%
Minibatch loss at step 750: 2.359751
Minibatch accuracy: 6.2%
Validation accuracy: 10.1%
Minibatch loss at step 1000: 2.273493
Minibatch accuracy: 12.5%`